# How to set up classes for Vue.js uiv library's Tab component?

Tags: vue.js, tabs, styles

We use uiv library in our project. We have tabs and I'd like to customize their UI. The documentation says:

https://uiv.wxsm.space/tabs#tab

I'm not sure how to use Tab's API, for example, to have different colors for different tabs under some circumstances.

I've tried simply this:

```
<tab
  v-for="(sectionDescription) in tabbedSectionDescriptions"
  :key="sectionDescription.key"
  :title="sectionDescription.displayName"
  :tab-classes="{ 'paint-tab': true }"
>

<style lang="stylus" scoped>
>>> .nav-tabs
  .paint-tab
    a
      color red
</style>
```

But, all tab's titles are painted in red, which is not behavior I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define function that return certian class object for certain tab:
in template:

```
:tab-classes="getTabColorClass(sectionDescription)"
```

in code:

```
methods: {
  getTabColorClass(sectionDescription) {
     switch (sectionDescription.key) {
       'key1': 
          return {
           'paint-tab': true 
          }
       'key2': 
         return {
           'paint-tab2': true 
         }
       default:
         return null
     }
  }
}
```

in style:

```
>>> .nav-tabs
  .paint-tab
    a
      color red
  .paint-tab2
    a
      color green
```